# NSManagedObject init/dealloc equivalent

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an object ivar `foo` inside a NSManagedObject subclass `bar` that I need to be there at all times, as long as the object exists.

To make sure `foo` is created properly, I've subclassed awakeFromInsert to create `foo` when `bar` is created. I've done the same in awakeFromFetch, to make sure `foo` is there when `bar` is fetched from the store.

To counteract that, I release `foo` inside willTurnIntoFault and in prepareForDeletion.

However, it turns out that when I do delete `bar`, both prepareForDeletion and then willTurnIntoFault are called, releasing `foo` twice.

I realize I can probably just not release it in prepareForDeletion then, but I'd like to know what the best practice is here, so I understand when something gets turned into a fault, etc. For a normal object, I'd just create `foo` in init and destroy it in dealloc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just releasing the ivar, release it and set it to `nil`. Releasing `nil` has no effect, so you'll be OK if it happens twice.

Better yet, make `foo` a property with `retain` semantics and always set it via `-setFoo:`.

Comment: I understand the first part, but what does making it a property with retain have to do with it? Or do you mean self.foo = nil, since that automatically releases the ivar?

Comment: Yes, if foo is declared as "@property (readwrite, retain)" and synthesized in your class's @implementation, then both [self setFoo:nil] and self.foo = nil will release it. (Also, setting it to a new value will release the old one.) It's a good habit to get into because you a) won't be as likely to forget to release ivars, and b) won't crash if you message the released ivar afterwards (because it will be nil).

Comment: Right, okay. So in init (generally, not in this case), I just create a local object for foo, do self.foo = whatever, and then [whatever release], right?

Comment: Yes, as long as you're creating the object in such a way that you own it (alloc/init, copy, etc.). Read http://bit.ly/dsVvdZ if you don't know what I'm talking about.